# how to do this conversion in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have varchar contains date in the formate ddmmyyyy hh:mm:mm:ss

I want to convert it to datetime with formate dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

any idea how to do that please

Comment: SQL database (within SQL server 2005)

Comment: A `DATETIME` in SQL Server does **not** have any format associated with it - it's just a 8-byte numeric value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @datestr varchar(20)
set @datestr = '31122012 10:00:00'
select convert(datetime, substring(@datestr, 1, 2) + '/' + 
                         substring(@datestr, 3, 2) + '/' + 
                         substring(@datestr, 5, 10), 
               103)
```